# How to make non-rectangular buttons in using windows.h in c++?

Tags: c++, windows, user-interface, button

I want to create a Polygon/Ellipse shape using the Polygon() or Ellipse() functions, and then map a button to have the same size and dimensions of the shape. Is this possible with only using windows.h, and no other gui libraries.

Here is some example code of creating a polygon and button, and I have overlapped them, the only problem is that because the button is a square, even when I click outside of the polygon it still activates the button even when the mouse is not inside of the polygon, also the button is on the top layer, which means the polygon is not visible.

```
HWND ButtonHWND = CreateWindow(
    _T("BUTTON"),
    _T("Click"),
    WS_TABSTOP | WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | BS_DEFPUSHBUTTON,
    100, 100,
    100, 100,
    hWnd,
    (HMENU)1,
    hInstance,
    NULL
);

if (!ButtonHWND) {
    MessageBox(NULL, _T("Call To CreateWindow Failed"), _T("Button"), NULL);
}

POINT Points[4];
Points[0] = { 100, 150 };
Points[1] = { 150, 200 };
Points[2] = { 200, 150 };
Points[3] = { 150, 100 };
Polygon(hdc, Points, 4);
```